# n-dimensional table lookup: array, dataframe, or dictionary?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to find the best way to do n-dimensional table lookups.  In this example, there is a dataframe that contains a person's state and the year, and I want to find the relevant tax rate by looking it up in a table (which could be an array, dataframe, or dictionary).  First, consider doing it via an array:

```
nobs = 4
df = DataFrame( { 'state' : np.tile( [ 'tx', 'ny'], nobs/2 ),
                  'year'  : np.tile( [ 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009 ], nobs/4 ) } )

dct = { 'tx':0, 'ny':1 }

# rows are 2008 and 2009, columns are 'tx' and 'ny'
rate_arr = np.array( [[.05,.06],
                      [.08,.09]] )

df['rate1'] = rate_arr[ df.year-2008, df.state.map(dct) ]

  state  year  rate1
0    tx  2008   0.05
1    ny  2008   0.06
2    tx  2009   0.08
3    ny  2009   0.09
```

The above is exactly what I want, I just want to see if there is a better way.  Like, any good way to label a numpy array?

Using a dataframe as a lookup would seem to give me the automatic translation of state and year values, but I can only get this to work for one dimension, not two:

```
rate_df = DataFrame( { 2008: [ .05, .06 ],
                       2009: [ .08, .09 ] } , index=(['tx','ny']) )

# doesn't work
df['rate3'] = rate_df[ df.year, df.state ]
```

Alternatively, maybe a nested dictionary?  Again, I can get this to work in one dimension but not two:

```
rate_dict = { 'tx': { 2008: .05, 2009: .08 },
              'ny': { 2008: .06, 2009: .09 } }

# doesn't work
df['rate2'] = df.year.map( df.state.map(rate_dict) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
In [21]: rate_df.lookup(df['state'], df['year'])
Out[21]: array([ 0.05,  0.06,  0.08,  0.09])

In [22]: df['rate2'] = res.lookup(df['state'], df['year'])

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
  state  year  rate1  rate2
0    tx  2008   0.05   0.05
1    ny  2008   0.06   0.06
2    tx  2009   0.08   0.08
3    ny  2009   0.09   0.09
```

---

Note: you can specify the index *and* columns to get a labelled DataFrame from a numpy array:

```
In [11]: rate_df = pd.DataFrame(rate_arr.T, index=['tx', 'ny'], columns=[2008, 2009])

In [12]: rate_df
Out[12]:
    2008  2009
tx  0.05  0.08
ny  0.06  0.09
```

*Update: I needed to transpose the numpy array so that `rate_df` was correctly oriented.*

Comment: @JohnE ah, you need to transpose the array (my rate_df was different from yours). Fixed in the edit!

Comment: Thanks Andy, that's awesome!  Btw, I fixed the data midstream.  You probably were working with my original data and that's why the transpose was needed.  My bad.

Comment: @JohnE no worries, easy fixes are the best kind - lookup is very neat!