# Efficient color lookup with linear interpolation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, colors, interpolation, lookup

I am interested in finding a fast method for looking up linearly interpolated colors from a defined lookup table. The purpose if to assign colors to a large number of items at run time based on a given color map. The colormap lookup table is a list of tuples that contains Values(Ascending), Red, Green, Blue, Opacity

Below is a simple recipe with standard python. 
I could also use pandas as I am using that for something else as well.

```
# Interpolate colors from a lookup table
import bisect

def find_color(x, vlist, lut):
    """Finds linearly interpolated color from specified lut and x
       Returns RGBA tuple
       Parameters
       x: value to lookup
       vlist: list of values in lut
       lut: List of tuples Value, R, G, B, A
    """
    last = len(lut) - 1 # last index for lut

    if x <= vlist[0] : #clamp low end
            return lut[0][1], lut[0][2], lut[0][3], lut[0][4]
    elif x >= vlist[last]: #clamp high end
            return lut[last][1], lut[last][2], lut[last][3], lut[last][4]
    else:
            # since vlist is sorted we can use bisect
            hi = bisect.bisect_left(vlist, x) #hi index
            lo = hi -  1 # lo index

            # interpolation weight from left
            w = ( x - vlist[lo] ) / (vlist[hi] -vlist[lo] )
            #print x, lo, hi, w

            # use w to interpolate r,g,b,a from lo and hi bins
            # interpolated_value = low_value + w * bin_size
            r = lut[lo][1]  + w * (lut[hi][1] - lut[lo][1])
            g = lut[lo][2]  + w * (lut[hi][2] - lut[lo][2])
            b = lut[lo][3]  + w * (lut[hi][3] - lut[lo][3])
            a = lut[lo][4]  + w * (lut[hi][4] - lut[lo][4])
            return int(r), int(g), int(b), int(a)


# Color lookup table
lut = [ (0.0, 255, 0, 0, 64),
     (0.5, 0, 255, 255,128),
     (1.0, 0, 0, 255, 255) ]

# Value list - extract first column from lut
vlist = [ x[0] for x in lut]

# Test find_color() for arbitrary value
for i in xrange(-5, 12):
    x = i/10.0
    print find_color(x, vlist, lut)
```

Comment: There are a variety of efficient ways to look things up in pandas, just search pandas for 'lookup' here and you'll find plenty.  I asked a question about n-dimensional lookups that received a good answer and may be similar to what you're trying to do:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772977/n-dimensional-table-lookup-array-dataframe-or-dictionary

Comment: I did do a search before posting, but the results that I came across were not for lookup with interpolation. I need to to do this repeatedly for 1000s of values, thus the need for efficiency. Also I am not using bumpy, but thanks for your thoughts

Comment: You sort of are using numpy if you use pandas since pandas is built on top of numpy ;-)  Also, you did mention efficiency and numpy will be much more efficient than standard python lists.  As far as lookup + interpolation, I don't think you will find that combo, but it seems your problem can just as well be approached in two steps -- 1. lookup, 2. interpolate.  FWIW.

Comment: Ahh did not know that pandas is built on numpy. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can pre-process your lookup table ahead of time, you can replace the binary search + interpolation with a simple lookup. That is as long as you're willing to accept the possibility of not fully accurate output, which should be the case for colors - off by one errors are very hard to detect.

Take the value and multiply it by some constant, then convert to integer, and use that integer as an index into a list.

```
resolution = 1024
multiplier = float(resolution) / (lut[-1][0] - lut[0][0])
lookup = [(0, 0, 0, 0)] * resolution
for index in range(resolution):
    r, g, b, a = find_color(lut[0][0] + i / multiplier, vlist, lut)
    lookup[index] = (r, g, b, a)

def find_color2(x):
    return lookup[int((x - lut[0][0]) * multiplier)]
```

Comment: My impression is that this won't work predictably unless I up the resolution significantly as  my data is double precision floats. Thanks for the idea though

Comment: @user3043805 go ahead and up the resolution then, memory is cheap. The precision of the values doesn't matter nearly as much as the distance between them, if you have two very close together you'll need high resolution but if they're all spread out you can use less. Try testing it and see.